# $ timeout <5> && react-scripts start && was unexpected at this time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
"scripts": {
    "build:css": "postcss src/styles/tailwind.css -o src/styles/app.css",
    "watch:css": "postcss src/styles/tailwind.css -o src/styles/app.css --watch",
    "react-scripts:start": "timeout <5> && react-scripts start",
    "react-scripts:dist": "react-scripts build",
    "start": "run-p watch:css react-scripts:start",
    "build": "run-s build:css react-scripts:dist",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

This is how my scripts part in my package.json looks. I keep getting "$ timeout <5> && react-scripts start && was unexpected at this time". I tried using sleep instead of timeout but that is unrecognized as a command. I tried downloading Windows Resource Tools Kit but that download is now unavailable.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve...  why would you do that? If you are trying to "wait" before you start, call the start after some time?

Comment: try this `timeout 5 /nobreak && react-scripts start`

Comment: I was following a tutorial and the person said that he will explain why later on so I was looking for a way to start the app without this error appearing.

Comment: Good then I add to the answers

Answer (score 0):

Something like this: `timeout 5 /nobreak && react-scripts start`

More [info](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html)